# define transform primitive "weekend" and define features using data frames

Tags: featuretools

i was trying to create a base line model with only one tranform primitive.

So i'm defining entities and relationships

eg: create entities and relationships. T

trans_primitives = [IsWeekend]

features = ft.dfs(entities=entities,

relationships=relationships,

```
  target_entity="trips",
```

trans_primitives=trans_primitives,

```
              agg_primitives=[],

              ignore_variables={"trips":
```

["pickup_latitude", "pickup_longitude",
"dropoff_latitude", "dropoff_longitude"]},

```
              features_only=True)
```

error is time index not found in dataframe

Comment: What version of Featuretools are you using? This appears to be the old API, which was update some time ago.

Comment: Also, it would be helpful if you could update your question to include the exact code you are using in the call to DFS and how you are defining the input parameter values to aid in troubleshooting.